# Spring Boot JPA native query for call PostgreSQL function

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am not familiar with the SQL function with spring boot. can anyone check my spring boot query whether it is correct?

I have created a PostgreSQL function and implemented it with spring boot.
but it is getting an error when I call the JPA query. below I have attached the SQL function  and JPA query

**PostgreSQL function - it is working fine**

```
select  pulse.fn_get_ticket_details_json(''::text,null::date,null::date,''::text)
```

**Spring boot query**

```
@Query(value = "select  pulse.fn_get_ticket_details_json(''::text,null::date,null::date,''::text)", nativeQuery = true)
JsonObject SearchData();
```

**Error message**

```
 ERROR: syntax error at or near ":"



Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet] with root cause

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near ":"
  Position: 44
```

**screenshot**
[image]

Comment: The colons are used by JPA for substitution variables. Can you escape the colon `:` with `\\:`?  So, your `::text,` should be `\\:\\:text,`

Comment: @gtiwari333 showing error     @Query(value = "select  pulse.fn_get_ticket_details_json(''::text,null::date,null::date,''\\:\\:text)", nativeQuery = true)

Comment: you have to do that for every occurrence of `:`

Comment: @gtiwari333 I have added a screenshot. could you please check.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
    @Query(value = "select pulse.fn_get_ticket_details_json(''\\:\\:text,null\\:\\:date,null\\:\\:date,''\\:\\:text)", nativeQuery = true)
```

Remove extra spaces and check your simple quotes.